# Solving the next Integral (by parts?)

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone give me a hint / help with the next integral? Thanks!

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}{x^{a-1}(t-x)^{b-1}dx}$$

Comment: do we know anything about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It is the Beta function of $a$ and $b$ if $t=1$.

Comment: Only that they are integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integral equals $t^{(a+b-1)}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma (a+b)}$

Take $y=xt$

Then we have,

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}{x^{a-1}(t-x)^{b-1}dx}=t^{(a+b-1)}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}{y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1}dx}=t^{(a+b-1)}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma (a+b)}$

Comment: This really works, I completely missed the Beta Function, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @Cardonai

Answer (score 0):

Sub $x=t u$ and get

$$t^{a+b-1} \int_0^1 du \, u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-1} = t^{a+b-1} \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$